# Using a 4-1 multiplexer

Tags: multiplexer

I have a 4-1 multiplexer. I am trying to learn how to use it and I understand the logic well enough, but since I have never had any electronics training, my knowledge is somewhat limited and without actual circuit diagrams on any online resource, it is very confusing. what I am confused about is how do you send inputs to the MUX. Do we need to have a full circuit from positive to ground and then have a branch coming out of that circuit going into the MUX? If someone could explain a simple input like say (0 1 0 1) with selectors (1 1) with a circuit diagram (which shows the power supply), that would be great.

Comment: The first place to start is the datasheet for the part you have. For one thing, we don't know if it is an analog or digital multiplexer. Some details will depend on the logic family and individual part details.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I did start with the datasheet (‎SN74HC153N) but I just wanna know how to connect a general multiplexer in a simple circuit. I know which pins to connect to for what for this specific multiplexer, but I have no idea how to connect them.

Comment: You need to provide a high or low voltage to each of the inputs. The simplest way is to wire some of the inputs to power/Vdd and some to ground/Vss. That is not a very useful configuration though, as the outputs will be constant.

Comment: What are you trying to do, really? If your goal is to learn discrete digital circuits, what made you choose this path to learn?

Comment: @Justin, I don't want a useful configuration. Once I understand how to wire things up, I will start controlling the inputs. I just got my hands on a RPi and a bunch of electrical components so I want to make something. I have one other question on here where I explained what I wanna do and that's where someone suggested multiplexers.

Comment: Think of each input as a stream of information coming into the device. It’s all serial data so you get to choose which data you want to “see”. Hence the select bits are how you toggle that selection. The output is based on which information you wanted to “see”. They can be good devices for selecting an I2C bus coming from a sensor or an EPROM, etc.

Comment: @KingDuken I understood that thankfully. It is just the wiring that I didn't understand

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita - Based on your other question, I just wanted to make sure you know that the output from each of your 10 detectors should be taken from the node between R3 and Q1 (the collector of Q1). Those  are probably the signals you should be sending to your mux data inputs.

Comment: @Justin, yes I know that, but thanks for your help! I am actually a physicist by trade, so I know very basic electronics (upto transistors I think). It is just complex components that are giving me a hard time

Comment: WARNING: Do not start off with your Pi. Put it away and get your bread board out and jumper wires. Here is a cheat sheet you might find useful.https://i.imgur.com/MaPDZvX.jpg. ***You said you understand the logic well enough***. Then your should understand the function table well enough and you can start messing around using the jumper wires.  I assume you have a multi-meter and an external 5V power supply. (Do not use the Rpi 5V rail, if you are a Rpi newbie, or you might fry it.). Have a couple of spare HC53s to fry, just in case. Good luck and good night. See you tomorrow.Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01, yes I am not messing with the RPi yet, which is why I wanted a simple circuit.  I was trying to work with LEDs on the breadboard but couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the advice! I bought like 15 spares just in case (I didn't know these are so cheap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the part you have is an [CMOS dual one-of-four digital multiplexer](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc153.pdf?ts=1600440600954&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DSN74HC153N).

[image]

With CMOS logic circuits you should tie **every single one of the inputs on the chip** to a valid logic level, either directly to a supply line or through a resistor.

The outputs can go somewhere (maybe a logic input or a resistor + LED, or even both if you keep the LED current low) **or** they can be left open.

An easy way to do that when you are playing with it on a solderless breadboard is to have a pullup or pulldown resistor such as 10K to a supply rail and use a switch to the opposite rail to control the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0GXXp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistors R2 R3 are optional if you don't use a switch. R1 is required, otherwise SW1 would short out the power supply when closed. In the latter circuit the input is high with SW1 open and low with SW1 closed.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!